# How to realloc an array of structs without a limit

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, structure, dynamic-memory-allocation

So basically, I have an array of structs which I have dynamically allocated.

```
  using namespace std;
  struct library
  {
    string bookname;
    string author;
    int bookno;
  };
  int main()
  {
           library *lib=NULL;
           lib=malloc(sizeof(lib)*1);
           lib=(library*)realloc(lib,2);
           cout<<"Enter Book Name: "<<endl;
           getline(cin,lib[i]->bookname);
 }
```

In the above program I'm creating a array of structure for a library. I have reallocated from 1 space to 2 spaces which can be increased to more. But I'm having problem in getting input to member variable of each array member. The lib[i] is causing error here.

Comment: You can't create instances of a non-pod class with `malloc`, or arrays of them. Use `new`, or placement `new` on that storage.

Comment: Or use a `std::vector`.

Comment: use `std::vector<library> my_library;`

Comment: `sizeof(lib)` is the same as `sizeof(library*)` and returns the size of the *pointer*.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I don't know if that's a good duplicate. The accepted (and only) answer uses placement `new` instead of something more rational like `std::vector` or even regular `new`.

Comment: @Blastfurnace You can improve that question by providing a better answer. Even though the current answer is flawed, the questions are still very similar.

Comment: You do the realloc right, but memory allocation do not create object (POD or not). You must use placement new as proposed in the link of François Andrieux. In c++ parlance `lib[i]->bookname` is an access to an object out of its lifetime period. The lifetime begin when the object is created by either its definition or a new expression.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux The proposed duplicate is quite different in that it does not ask for a way to allocate a dynamic array of objects using `malloc` but a single object. To be a good duplicate, you would have to explain how you need to copy memory using `std::unitialized_copy` (maybe combined with a move iterator), when doing `realloc` + placement `new` on the remaining elements, which would not be an answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: `lib=malloc(sizeof(lib)*1);` -- This will not compile using C++, since the return value for `malloc` must be casted to a pointer of the type being assigned to.  If you were using a `C` compiler, *then* this would compile without casting.  Second, and I have to ask this -- where are you getting the idea to use `malloc`, `realloc`, and all of these `C`-ish things in a C++ program?  If it's in a book, throw the book away -- if it's a teacher, get a new teacher.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie This is a typo. corrections made

Comment: @Oliv Unless you are working with OP, you don't know that for sure. It could well be that OP does not know how to use `malloc` with `sizeof`.

Comment: Why oh why would you be using C++, but still calling malloc?

Comment: sorry about the code @PaulMcKenzie, I've been learning online and pdfs... I havent read enough of dynamic allocation and reallocation of structures using 'new' operator so I avoided using it.

Comment: For the love of $DEITY, just use `std::vector` already.

Comment: @ArohanAjit That's not going to work well for you. You'll learn better and faster with [a good C++ book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Trust me.

Comment: @ArohanAjit -- *I havent read enough of dynamic allocation and reallocation of structures using 'new' operator so I avoided using it* -- Which probably means you are reading `C` material, not `C++` material, and decided to go with `C` routines.  I know of no C++ tutorial, book, pdf, good or bad, that teaches you `malloc` and `realloc` as the dynamic allocation routines to use in a C++ program.

Comment: @ArohanAjit I have learn C++ with Stroustrup book (The C++ programming language) but "Programming principle and practice using C++" (second edition) may be more adequate if you have never programmed before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `struct library` has `std::string` members, so isn't a "POD" (plain-old data) class. This means that simple C memory allocation isn't going to work, because the string constructors and destructors will not be called.

The easiest way of doing what you want to do is simply to use `std::vector<library>`. This will run the constructors and destructors correctly, and will resize itself automatically. If you want to, you can manually control the allocated size of the `vector` with `reserve()` and `shrink_to_fit()`.

If you really, really must use `malloc()` and friends, then you will need to use placement `new` and a manual destructor call. Something like the following may work:

```
library *lib = nullptr;
lib = static_cast<library*>(malloc(sizeof(library)*2)); // note not sizeof(lib)
lib = new (lib) library[2]{}; // default construct an array of library at the given location
cout<<"Enter Book Name: "<<endl;
getline(cin,lib[0].bookname);
// ...do other library stuff...
lib[0].~library(); // destroy librarys
lib[1].~library();
free(lib); // deallocate storage
```

But note that you still can't use `realloc()`. You'll have to create a new array, invoke copy/move constructors with placement new, and then destroy and delete the original array.

Or just use `std::vector`, which does all this for you.

Answer (score 0):

From just looking at the code there are several things wrong

1. you stated your problem is coming from: `lib[i]` Well, the code snippet provided never declares `i`
2. `lib` is a pointer and when you use `[]` with a pointer you are referencing it meaning the `->` will not work instead just use `.` like so: `lib[i].bookname`
3. Tristan Brindle is correct you need to use `new`

Comment: Actually I declared the i earlier in the program, I just added the necessary part because it was tedious copying everything for ubuntu. But thanks for the advising . instead of -> thing. It worked!